# How does OpenSea get Town Star ERC1155 token image?

Tags: etherscan, erc-1155, opensea

I find that contract of Town Star ERC1155 token ABI does not have `uri` function [code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc36cf0cfcb5d905b8b513860db0cfe63f6cf9f5c#code)

And I try to use OpenSea API to check a metadate for a random token I choose [This one](https://opensea.io/assets/0xc36cf0cfcb5d905b8b513860db0cfe63f6cf9f5c/122161369724616908383351484068004787912704).

API call `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?asset_contract_address=0xc36cf0cfcb5d905b8b513860db0cfe63f6cf9f5c&token_ids=122161369724616908383351484068004787912704` response as below:

```
{"assets":[{"id":29329471,"token_id":"122161369724616908383351484068004787912704","num_sales":56,"background_color":null,"image_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/sFXH5WPo8nACwhdrtbSBHqvondVjWUJ-pWxacKwOIPF36J_2ZIGgVSuMSi3yqJY15UpdRbPMjEYV93fYXfCNqiDyguUgf2SFQny8UCA","image_preview_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/sFXH5WPo8nACwhdrtbSBHqvondVjWUJ-pWxacKwOIPF36J_2ZIGgVSuMSi3yqJY15UpdRbPMjEYV93fYXfCNqiDyguUgf2SFQny8UCA=s250","image_thumbnail_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/sFXH5WPo8nACwhdrtbSBHqvondVjWUJ-pWxacKwOIPF36J_2ZIGgVSuMSi3yqJY15UpdRbPMjEYV93fYXfCNqiDyguUgf2SFQny8UCA=s128","image_original_url":"https://tokens.gala.games/images/sandbox-games/town-star/skins/mirandus-fabric-plant-skin.png","animation_url":null,"animation_original_url":null,"name":"Mirandus Fabric Plant Skin","description":"Changes the look of your Fabric Plant to be Mirandus themed!","external_link":null,"asset_contract":{"address":"0xc36cf0cfcb5d905b8b513860db0cfe63f6cf9f5c","asset_contract_type":"semi-fungible","created_date":"2020-06-15T19:18:12.470039","name":"Gala Games","nft_version":null,"opensea_version":null,"owner":7360995,"schema_name":"ERC1155","symbol":"","total_supply":null,"description":"From one of the founders of Zynga and some of the creative minds behind FarmVille and Words With Friends comes Town Star. Blockchain is the next evolution of gaming and has the $148B industry buzzing with excitement. It’s gaming re-imagined to benefit creators and players, alike.","external_link":"https://www.gala.games/","image_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wp7V1K4Ezhi8yHU6LFpff-GMsjend65nRiwNz5pGAjCwk7ybznEpfUvXiIxQoOWBmeN00AGjVTRhLUqY4fee1fus=s120","default_to_fiat":false,"dev_buyer_fee_basis_points":0,"dev_seller_fee_basis_points":250,"only_proxied_transfers":false,"opensea_buyer_fee_basis_points":0,"opensea_seller_fee_basis_points":250,"buyer_fee_basis_points":0,"seller_fee_basis_points":500,"payout_address":"0xa92abb0d0dd1e8e73006fc3b6229b7bd9e0d5c61"},"permalink":"https://opensea.io/assets/0xc36cf0cfcb5d905b8b513860db0cfe63f6cf9f5c/122161369724616908383351484068004787912704","collection":{"banner_image_url":null,"chat_url":null,"created_date":"2020-07-07T04:21:17.383133","default_to_fiat":false,"description":"From one of the founders of Zynga and some of the creative minds behind FarmVille and Words With Friends comes Town Star. Blockchain is the next evolution of gaming and has the $148B industry buzzing with excitement. It’s gaming re-imagined to benefit creators and players, alike.","dev_buyer_fee_basis_points":"0","dev_seller_fee_basis_points":"250","discord_url":null,"display_data":{"card_display_style":"padded"},"external_url":"https://www.gala.games/","featured":false,"featured_image_url":null,"hidden":false,"safelist_request_status":"verified","image_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wp7V1K4Ezhi8yHU6LFpff-GMsjend65nRiwNz5pGAjCwk7ybznEpfUvXiIxQoOWBmeN00AGjVTRhLUqY4fee1fus=s120","is_subject_to_whitelist":false,"large_image_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wp7V1K4Ezhi8yHU6LFpff-GMsjend65nRiwNz5pGAjCwk7ybznEpfUvXiIxQoOWBmeN00AGjVTRhLUqY4fee1fus","medium_username":"GoGalaGames","name":"Town Star","only_proxied_transfers":false,"opensea_buyer_fee_basis_points":"0","opensea_seller_fee_basis_points":"250","payout_address":"0xa92abb0d0dd1e8e73006fc3b6229b7bd9e0d5c61","require_email":false,"short_description":null,"slug":"town-star","telegram_url":"https://t.me/GoGalaGames","twitter_username":"GoGalaGames","instagram_username":null,"wiki_url":null},"decimals":null,"token_metadata":"https://tokens.gala.games/sandbox-games/town-star/skins/mirandus-fabric-plant-skin.json","owner":{"user":{"username":"NullAddress"},"profile_img_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/1.png","address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","config":""},"sell_orders":[{"created_date":"2022-01-11T05:48:40.269327","closing_date":"2022-07-11T05:48:15","closing_extendable":false,"expiration_time":1657518495,"listing_time":1641880003,"order_hash":"0xbf2c9369b948b835232088755d96bb66ef2edea01d13b42428dae3e242078c75","metadata":{"asset":{"id":"122161369724616908383351484068004787912704","address":"0xc36cf0cfcb5d905b8b513860db0cfe63f6cf9f5c","quantity":"1"},"schema":"ERC1155"},"exchange":"0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b","maker":{"user":11403466,"profile_img_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/26.png","address":"0x1c50bb18b4ec35103bccc10b76e9afdb289b975a","config":""},"taker":{"user":1766,"profile_img_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/1.png","address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","config":""},"current_price":"3796000000.000000000000000000","current_bounty":"37960000","bounty_multiple":"0.01","maker_relayer_fee":"500","taker_relayer_fee":"0","maker_protocol_fee":"0","taker_protocol_fee":"0","maker_referrer_fee":"0","fee_recipient":{"user":3585,"profile_img_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/28.png","address":"0x5b3256965e7c3cf26e11fcaf296dfc8807c01073","config":"verified"},"fee_method":1,"side":1,"sale_kind":0,"target":"0xc36cf0cfcb5d905b8b513860db0cfe63f6cf9f5c","how_to_call":0,"calldata":"0xf242432a0000000000000000000000001c50bb18b4ec35103bccc10b76e9afdb289b975a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","replacement_pattern":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","static_target":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","static_extradata":"0x","payment_token":"0x15d4c048f83bd7e37d49ea4c83a07267ec4203da","payment_token_contract":{"id":318,"symbol":"GALA","address":"0x15d4c048f83bd7e37d49ea4c83a07267ec4203da","image_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1DcP21E8JYH0YEvBF9HD2R4LrK742KQGJyumV5kJkAxRp2wEdOcQrvsVJmUIaNJMVkFKyxSMLZRVA-sBGfCnoEDD=s120","name":"Gala","decimals":8,"eth_price":"0.000100560000000","usd_price":"0.327482000000000000"},"base_price":"3796000000","extra":"0","quantity":"1","salt":"13486021474025852519810271922175260653938170746936005350352089145218669257494","v":28,"r":"0x05539ff3074fc24fd81605aed846a6636aa4c841f7c75ac27a5b6900f2c396c2","s":"0x4dc37f0182ccf337bfca2a91d759f061dbe57353c69100f95f22f20dec821eb5","approved_on_chain":false,"cancelled":false,"finalized":false,"marked_invalid":false,"prefixed_hash":"0x0137d05a6d560944002aad2be4cfbaa91f71a38308894d032314e8e589da572d"}],"creator":{"user":null,"profile_img_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/17.png","address":"0x0d24de9dccd263b310b7809283786c58d1f6a667","config":""},"traits":[{"trait_type":"game","value":"Town Star","display_type":null,"max_value":null,"trait_count":239,"order":null},{"trait_type":"category","value":"Skins","display_type":null,"max_value":null,"trait_count":71,"order":null},{"trait_type":"tokenRun","value":"skins","display_type":null,"max_value":null,"trait_count":71,"order":null}],"last_sale":{"asset":{"token_id":"122161369724616908383351484068004787912704","decimals":null},"asset_bundle":null,"event_type":"successful","event_timestamp":"2022-01-13T20:21:09","auction_type":null,"total_price":"41400000000000000","payment_token":{"id":1,"symbol":"ETH","address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","image_url":"https://storage.opensea.io/files/6f8e2979d428180222796ff4a33ab929.svg","name":"Ether","decimals":18,"eth_price":"1.000000000000000","usd_price":"3266.159999999999854000"},"transaction":{"block_hash":"0x527bc881a7162b949d7dfad15b37b852cf92cd99b613dde02afb8acdf1ab3a79","block_number":"13999276","from_account":{"user":{"username":null},"profile_img_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/9.png","address":"0x0ddb92119f32ae8b49b4143e404d023edbc4a5c8","config":""},"id":247299588,"timestamp":"2022-01-13T20:21:09","to_account":{"user":{"username":"OpenSea-Orders"},"profile_img_url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/opensea-profile/22.png","address":"0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b","config":"verified"},"transaction_hash":"0xb53a5518d0a0b8aabfe7f1945cfdc77f05d5f71e15a73cba683143e2cbaf1efc","transaction_index":"25"},"created_date":"2022-01-13T20:21:25.825679","quantity":"6"},"top_bid":null,"listing_date":null,"is_presale":false,"transfer_fee_payment_token":null,"transfer_fee":null}]}
```

And there has a key `token_metadata` shows `https://tokens.gala.games/sandbox-games/town-star/skins/mirandus-fabric-plant-skin.json`

The metadata contain image uri for token (https://tokens.gala.games/images/sandbox-games/town-star/skins/mirandus-fabric-plant-skin.png)

But... since ABI does not have `uri` function, how does OpenSea get that metadata uri (https://tokens.gala.games/sandbox-games/town-star/skins/mirandus-fabric-plant-skin.json)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!

Town Star token is an ERC1155 token. The `tokenURI` property is part of the ERC20 token specification. Hence, you won't find it in Town Star's contract. According to the [docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155), ERC1155's version of `tokenURI` is called `IERC1155MetadataURI` and is totally optional.

However, Town Star does contain the URI in a different place. If you look at the contract on etherscan, the `create` function looks like this.

```js
function create(string calldata _uri, bool _isNF) external creatorOnly returns (uint256 _type) {

        _type = (++nonce << 128);
        if (_isNF) _type = _type | TYPE_NF_BIT;
        emit TransferSingle(msg.sender, address(0x0), address(0x0), _type, 0);


        if (bytes(_uri).length > 0) emit URI(_uri, _type);
        // the above line emits an event
  
        return _type;
    }
```

You can see that the create function takes in a URI in `_uri` parameter, but instead of storing it, it emits an event - `URI`. The event URI has the following definition in the contract.

```js
event URI(string _value, uint256 indexed _id);
```

The `topic_0` of this function is `0x6bb7ff708619ba0610cba295a58592e0451dee2622938c8755667688daf3529b`. If you search the logs in etherscan with this `topic_0`, you'll be able to see all the events emitted, thus all the token URI. I'm adding a screenshot for reference.

[image: Screenshot of logs of URI events of Town Star contract]

Events can also be used as cheap storage in the EVM blockchains. It costs less gas than storage. The devs of Town Star have decided to use events to store the URI.

Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: So, does it means that OpenSean need to parse events logs and get least event value to get metadata? [Like this](https://pastebin.com/bS9W41Tt)

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote...